How to check for singular matrix in C
In python, we have a way to efficient check for singular matrix here:
if linalg.cond(x) < 1/sys.float_info.epsilon:
    i = linalg.inv(x)
else:
    #handle it

But how can we do similar way in the C programming launguage?

Write an implementation of that cond() method? Or find a matrix library to use.

The words "python" and "efficient" really shouldn't appear in the same sentence.  Perhaps you are using a different definition of "efficient" than one typically sees in a discussion about C.

Because the reference post used "efficient" word, I think that means fast. But what "efficient" means that one typically sees in a discussion about C? Is it fast?

@WilliamPursell Well, some dedicated math libraries, such as the (implicitly) aforementioned NumPy are quite optimized and efficient (they are written in C and C++ where the bottlenecks are expected). One might have some hard time to implement the same as efficient from scratch in C.

@minhquýlê Read about which algorithm NumPy is using, then re-implement it in C. Or look at it's sources (it is open-source) which are likely in C or C++.

NumPy hands its mathematically heavy matrix operations over to C numerical libraries  LApack or BLAS as it explains here. So you should be able to call the appropriate routine directly from C after installing the library code.
